# How do I check that array size?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print all the time of Jobs with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = 'cases/case1_1md_2mec_4jobs.xlsx'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)

df_jobs = xl.parse('Jobs')
df_mecs = xl.parse('MECs')
df_links = xl.parse('Links')
df_mds =   xl.parse('MD')


df_sol_time = pd.DataFrame(columns={'Jobs','Time'})
for job in df_jobs:
    job_size = df_jobs['JOB SIZE'][df_jobs['ID'] == job].item()
    MD_ID = df_jobs['MD ID'][df_jobs['ID'] == job].item()
    md_proc_speed = df_mds['PROCESSOR'][df_mds['MD ID'] == MD_ID].item()
    comp_time = float(job_size * 1024 * 1024 * 8) / (0.00227 * md_proc_speed)
```

I am getting this message:

> Can only convert an array of size 1 to a python scalar

Comment: And the error occurs on line? I'm guessing that df_jobs isn't what you're expecting.

Comment: I'm guessing one of the `item` calls is raising this issue. But which?  What's the indexing result before that call?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand fully, but I'm fairly certain this will take away your scalar error and should give you what you were trying to get out of the dictionaries.

```py
for index, job in df_jobs.iterrows():
    job_size = job['JOB SIZE']
    MD_ID = job['MD ID']
    md_proc_speed = job['PROCESSOR']
    comp_time = float(job_size * 1024 * 1024 * 8) / (0.00227 * md_proc_speed)
```

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking to print, but perhaps this will help.

```py
for index, job in df_jobs.iterrows():
    job_size = job['JOB SIZE']
    MD_ID = job['MD ID']
    md_proc_speed = job['PROCESSOR']
    comp_time = float(job_size * 1024 * 1024 * 8) / (0.00227 * md_proc_speed)
    print(MD_ID, comp_time)
```

For a total time.

```py
total_comp_time = 0
for index, job in df_jobs.iterrows():
    job_size = job['JOB SIZE']
    MD_ID = job['MD ID']
    md_proc_speed = job['PROCESSOR']
    comp_time = float(job_size * 1024 * 1024 * 8) / (0.00227 * md_proc_speed)
    print(MD_ID, comp_time)
    total_comp_time += comp_time
print(total_comp_time)
```

Comment: I have four jobs . J1: 2 MB , J2:1, J3:4, J4:5. I am trying to find out the time of all jobs with the equations in the above code. I have tried print (MD_ID, comp_time) but It didn't solve the issue

Comment: Are you looking for the total of all the jobs?

Comment: Yes, Individuals time of all the jobs

Comment: Ahh, I think; I see the issue we are using the pandas object incorrectly. I will correct the above code. If that doesn't solve the issue; you may need to provide some sample data for me to evaluate the code further.

Comment: Here I am getting this error now:   job_size = job['JOB SIZE'].item()
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: You probably don't need the .item() method at all. Whenever you provide the key for a dictionary it returns the dictionaries item. You are probably performing that .item() method on your data value. I will correct the above code to reflect this.